# Do we need transit visa in Frankfurt?

Tags: indian-citizens, germany, transit-visas, schengen-visas

We are a family of 13 travelling from Mumbai to Istanbul via Frankfurt and return in the same direction. we have 4 hours layover each way, do we need a transit visa for Germany?

Comment: In any event, we can't offer much help without knowing your nationality.  If all 13 of you are Indian citizens traveling with Indian passports then you will need 13 airport transit visas.

Answer (score 2):

[If you are citizens of India you need visas, even if remaining airside, unless certain exceptions apply.](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/aamt/zugastimaa/buergerservice/faq/33-transit/606710) Most Schengen States do not require visas for airside transit for Indian citizens, but Germany does.

[Visas can be applied for at a German mission or a visa application centre.](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/service/-/1908794)